# Smalltalk - collection is empty error when saving

Tags: smalltalk

Does anyone know what would cause this? I can't save anything to my class because I get a debugging exception thrown: Collection is empty

[image]

---

Link to source:  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1817765/Pharo%20Crash%20Files.rar

Steps to recreate:

- Launch Pharo 1.1
- Select the `.image` file, **without** the `.changes` file in the same directory
- Attempt to select `NumberWithUnits>>=`

  - Crash
- Attempt to save *almost* anything to `NumberWithUnits`

  - Crash

Comment: From the picture, it looks like a squeak 4.x flavour. Which version exactly? It looks like a bug, so you'll probably have to dump the stack and post it to squeak-dev mailing list (or open a mantis issue).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Squeak/Pharo have special handling in case of absent source code: they try and decompile CompiledMethod from appropriate MethodDictionary.

What you saw here is a failure of Decompiler to properly decompile some method.

Without code, the IDE is non functional, and you are stuck (you can't save your code, browse your code, debug your code...)

This Pharo 1.1 version is very old and you won't get any support on it.

But interestingly, the bug of Decompiler that you encountered is still present on current Squeak trunk development (4.5)
And the method that makes the Decompiler loosy is:

```
< aNumberWithUnits
    (self compareUnits: aNumberWithUnits) 
        ifTrue: [self value: ((aNumberWithUnits value) < (self value) ifTrue: [^true] ifFalse: [^false]).] 
        ifFalse: [^Error new signal: 'Incompatible unit types.'].
```

This is a rather unconventional code since the message `[self value: ...]` will never be sent.
The reason is that the parameter will be evaluated first, and both branches of the condition will return `ifTrue: [^true] ifFalse: [^false]`.

Since you explored some dark corner that only newbies do explore, and that we failed to test, I'd just say thank you.

If you feel like it, you can open a report on http://bugs.squeak.org

Answer (score 6):

The issue was that I didn't have the correct `.changes` file associated with my project. Since my teammate and I were collaborating, these were lost in translation. Once I placed the correct `.changes` files in the directory of my `.image` file, everything worked out.

Comment: Good, but the Decompiler is used to reconstruct the source code in this case, and there is a second issue: it failed. Could you share the source code that made it fail?

Comment: Added a download link with recreation steps to the original question

Comment: Ah thanks, this version of Pharo is old, and investigating this small Decompiler problem would just be wasted time knowing that many things are happening right now in development branch (3.0) precisely about Compiler, Decompiler, and sometimes soon source code storage. I'll try to check in Squeak though.